# Intel MKL Pardiso solver compiling with Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, linker, fortran, intel-mkl, pardiso

I am trying to do create a simple example in order to use the Pardiso solver inside MKL Intel library. I have been following the examples provided but if I place the call to Pardiso in a subroutine it does not work. I am afraid that is something related to the INCLUDE statement or the linking aspect.

Arrays used by all subroutines are contained in a module called variables

```
MODULE variables
INTEGER :: M        ! Lines
INTEGER :: N        ! Columns
REAL*8, DIMENSION(:,:), ALLOCATABLE :: MATRA ! original matrix
INTEGER, DIMENSION(:), ALLOCATABLE :: ROWSA,COLSA ! ia and ja in pardiso
REAL*8,    dimension(:), ALLOCATABLE :: VALSA, RHSVC, SOLVC ! a, b, x
END MODULE variables
```

The file containing the program is as follows:

```
INCLUDE 'mkl_pardiso.f90'
program PardisoFortran
use variables
use mkl_pardiso
implicit none

! do some stuff to create the matrices
call create_matrices

call INITPARDISO

end program
```

Finally the file initpardiso

```
subroutine INITPARDISO
USE VARIABLES
USE mkl_pardiso

! pardiso variable declaration    
TYPE(MKL_PARDISO_HANDLE), ALLOCATABLE  :: pt(:)
INTEGER maxfct, mnum, mtype, phase, nrhs, error, msglvl
INTEGER, ALLOCATABLE, DIMENSION(:) :: iparm
INTEGER i, idum
REAL*8 waltime1, waltime2, ddum

! --- then I allocate and fill the variables

! Finally I can call pardiso
phase = 11 ! only reordering and symbolic factorization phase

CALL pardiso_64 (PT, maxfct, mnum, mtype, phase, M, VALSA, COLSA, &
              ROWSA, idum, nrhs, iparm, msglvl, ddum, ddum, error)

end subroutine
```

Now, I added also the Additional Include Directories to Visual Studio project configuration (that is

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\ComposerXE-2011\mkl\include;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\ComposerXE-2011\mkl\lib\intel64;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\ComposerXE-2011\mkl\lib\ia32)
```

If I comment the call to pardiso everything works perfectly, otherwise it stops compilation with this error:

Error   1    error #6285: There is no matching specific subroutine for this generic subroutine call.   [PARDISO_64] ....PardisoFortran\initpardiso.f    144

Any idea for that? Is that a problem of the INCLUDE statement on top? where should I include it?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that `pardiso_64` is a subroutine version which uses 64-bit integers.  Your code snippets show no evidence that you have taken measures to ensure that your integers are 64-bit.  I suppose you may have used compiler options or other means to tell the compiler to default to 64-bit integers.

The error message you post is typical of the error messages you get when there is a mis-match between dummy and actual arguments when calling a library generic procedure.  Suppose that your integers are only 32-bit, then the compiler is looking for, and failing to find, a routine named `pardiso_64` which takes 32-bit integer arguments.

I don't think that the error has anything to do with the `include` statement.

Comment: Let's see.. I corrected all variables to make them be the same as the manual says. All integer variables array are now INTEGER(KIND=8) and REAL(KIND=8). PT is a MKL_pardiso_handle type and I am compiling in Debug 64bit. The problem is still there, and the message does not change.... it is a bit frustrating...

Comment: Just an Update: the problem was the call, actually it is not pardiso_64 but pardiso_D_64 (where D stand for doubles). I feel there is an issue with the interface of pardiso/MKL since in the manual they do not expect this. In addition, using a matrix that even Matlab can solve easily, Pardiso is stuck with a "reordering problem".

Answer (score 0):

I see one problem in your code. The parameter 'ddum' was a scalar. It should be an array of dimension (M, nrhs). There could be more problems. I need to see the entire code to help.

As usual, the best place to ask Intel MKL related questions is the MKL forum: http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-math-kernel-library. Post your question there, with your entire program attached. You will get an answer much quicker!